# Can I use multiple joker tokens in one buying a development card action?

Tags: splendor

If I have two jokers can I use them as two colours on one purchase, or only one at a time? If multiple are okay, do they have to be for the same colour or different okay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the rules

> Buying a development card 
>  To purchase a card, a player must spend the
> number of tokens indicated on the card. A joker token can replace any
> color. The spent tokens (including any jokers) are returned to the
> middle of the table.

The rules mentions the plural form of joker and each joker is evaluated on its own -> you can use two jokers in one buying action and use them for different colours.